# htaccess rewrite and redirection for SEO friendly URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I know that this question may be duplicate or answered in the past but I have read the apache.org site and have seen many other similar answers and I cannot find a proper solution to my problem so far since I am novice in the .htaccess and apache.

For simplicity reasons let's assume that the URL of my site is: `https://www.example.com`

The main page is `index.php` and there is a submit form with 3 select/dropdowns elements with names: `sp`, `ar` and `in`. `sp` is mandatory (user has to enter a value), `ar` and `in` are optionals.

When I submit the form, the file `results.php` is executed. When all 3 dropdowns have values, the form of the submitted URL is:

```
1) https://www.example.com/results.php?sp=textvalue1&ar=textvalue2&in=textvalue3
```

Moreover, depending if the `ar` and `in` have (or haven't) values, the other possible forms of the URL are:

```
2) https://www.example.com/results.php?sp=textvalue1&ar=&in= 
3) https://www.example.com/results.php?sp=textvalue1&ar=textvalue2&in= 
4) https://www.example.com/results.php?sp=textvalue1&ar=&in=textvalue3
```

I want to convert these "ugly" URLs to SEO-friendly URLs.

For case 1 (all 3 dropdowns have values), I would like to submit the form and see in my browser's URL field:

```
(case 1) https://www.example.com/textvalue1/textvalue2/textvalue3
```

and get the same results (important)!

Similarly, I want the other SEO-friendly URLs to be:

```
(case 2) https://www.example.com/textvalue1
(case 3) https://www.example.com/textvalue1/textvalue2
(case 4) https://www.example.com/textvalue1/textvalue3
```

My guess is that I have to do 2 things: First, to convert the ugly URL to a SEO-friendly URL and, second, to treat the new SEO-friendly URL as if it was the old ugly one.

I have tried the following commands in my `.htaccess` file for case 2 so far but nothing happened:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/results\.php\?sp=([a-zA-Z]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^/([[a-zA-Z]]+)$ /results.php?sp=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This won't work. Certainly you can implement redirection and rewriting rules for this. But you have, as far as I can tell, no way to decide what a URL like `https://www.example.com/foo/bar` actually tries to express: what is `bar` meant to be a value for? `ar` or `in`?

Comment: But what about using multiple/different conditions and rules, one for each case?

Comment: Sure, _if you can name conditions_ to tell both meanings apart, then you can implement those. But you did not name any in your question. So what are they?

Comment: I am a little confused by your answer. As far as I know, there is no need to name the conditions, only to use the right regex values in order to decide where to apply the RewriteRule.

Comment: The issue is not whether you can apply a rule. You are absolutely right that you just need to have a matching regular expression. The issue I point out here is: if you have a matching regular expression for the example URL I mentioned in my first comment, then what GET argument will you assign the value `bar` to that you captured in the incoming request? Will you assign it to `ar` or to `in`? This is not defined in any way in your question and I cannot sport any logic for that. So again: can you name a condition or a logic by which to decide what case is actually meant by the URL?

Comment: I will make it easier for you: Give me a working solution for case 1 (all 3 parameters have text values) and I will be ok.

Comment: Sure, did that, even for two of the three cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already discussed in the comments to the question I see an issue with the question regarding the rewriting logic. You asked to show a more simplified approach for the situation where all three request arguments are present. Here is a suggestion that also handles the case where only two arguments are specified. You don't even need conditions for that, the matching pattern is enough for such logic:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /results.php?sp=$1&ar=$2&in=$3 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /results.php?sp=$1&ar=$2 [END]

RewriteCond ${QUERY_STRING} ^sp=(.+)&ar=(.+)&in=(.+)$  
RewriteRule ^/results\.php$ /%1/%2/%3 [R=301,END]
RewriteCond ${QUERY_STRING} ^sp=(.+)&ar=(.+)$  
RewriteRule ^/results\.php$ /%1/%2 [R=301,END]
```

That rule set will work likewise in the http servers host configuration and also in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file). A general remark here: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

In case you experience an "internal server error" (http status 500) using above rule set then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. In that case replace the `END` flag with the `L` flag. You will find a specific hint on the unsupported END flag in your http servers error log file in that case.

Once more: *if* you can name a logic by which to decide which request argument to assign the second value captured by the second rule if it gets applied, *then* it would be possible to implement such a condition and handle all three cases you originally mentioned. But without you specifying such logic it is impossible to implement something.

Comment: I used all the lines of your code except for the last one. I wrote https://www.example.com/value1/value2/value3 in the URL field of my browser and it fetched me the right results but the URL remains "ugly" (https://www.example.com?sp=value1&ar=value2&in=value3). We are half-way there...

Comment: I do have to apologize, you are absolutely right. I adjusted the answer and added the reverse rule set. Please give it another try.

Comment: Seems to work! You are the man! I guess that some broken images that appear now in the results page need an absolute path and not relative path, right?

Comment: One final question: When I enter https://www.example.com/value1/value2/value3, the page has the desired behaviour. But when I submit the page, the url remains ugly  (https://example.com?sp=value1&ar=value2&in=value3). Strange.  Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: If the images worked before the rewriting then you do not need to change how they are referenced. More likely the rewriting logic above is also applied to them. Keep in mind that the rewriting rule rewrites _all_ requests matching the pattern `/.../.../...`, regardless of what is requested. So the best is to add another condition to prevent rewriting in that case. Again you need to name a condition. Maybe the images have a common folder they are kept in? You need to tell us...

Comment: `example.com?sp=value1&ar=value2&in=value3` is _not_ the URL for form submissions you claimed to be used in the question. There is was `https://www.example.com/results.php?sp=textvalue1&ar=textvalue2&in=textvalue3`. Now is there a `results.php` in there or not? Can it be that you have other rewriting rules in place too?